# WPF: How to prevent CheckBox.Checked event from being fired for ComboBox as a ToggleButton?

Tags: wpf, combobox, checkbox, routedevent

I have a lots of controls in a Window including checkboxes and comboboxes. I want to track CheckBox.IsChecked event, so I defined an event handler in Windows level as

```
<Grid CheckBox.Checked="OnModified" CheckBox.Unchecked="OnModified">
```

The problem is that the same event is also fired by ComboBox right after mouse clicking an item. I thought my event handler should only capture CheckBox's Checked event, not ToggleButton's. Did I miss anything?

EDIT: 
As I pointed out below, I thought it would work this way because I read **Matthew MacDonald's** book "**Pro WPF in C# 2010**". **On page 164**, he gave this example code first:

```
<StackPanel Button.Click="DoSomething" Margin="5">   
  <Button Name="cmd1">Command 1</Button> 
  <Button Name="cmd2">Command 2</Button> 
  <Button Name="cmd3">Command 3</Button> 
  ... 
</StackPanel>
```

Then, he specially noted:

> Note  The Click event is actually
>   defined in the ButtonBase class and
>   inherited by the Button class. If you
>   attach  an event handler to
>   ButtonBase.Click, that event handler
>   will be used when any
>   ButtonBase-derived control is  clicked
>   (including the Button, RadioButton,
>   and CheckBox classes). If you attach
>   an event handler to Button.Click, 
>   it’s only used for Button objects.

Now, did I misunderstand him, or is his note wrong?

Comment: how is your event handler being "attached"? some code would be good!

Comment: Okay, I edited the question to include some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not actually a separate `CheckBox.Checked` event.  If you look at this page:

- [CheckBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox.aspx)

and find the `Checked` event you will see that it is inherited from `ToggleButton` so `ToggleButton.Checked` and `CheckBox.Checked` are two different names for the same event.

Since you are subscribing to a "wildcard" event, in the event handler you can check the sender or source to see you it is one you are interested in.

**Edit:**

To address your follow-on question regarding the book quote, I think the quote is at least misleading.  Here is a counter-example that shows a `CheckBox` reacting to `Button` event even though `CheckBox` is not derived from `Button`:

```
<CheckBox Button.Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
```

Of course there is no `Button.Click` event, only a `ButtonBase.Click` event, but that is the crux of the quote.  If the quote were literally true, either this syntax would not be permitted or the event wouldn't fire, neither of which is true.

Comment: I thought I have read somewhere (in a book?) that there is a distinction between CheckBox.Checked and ToggleButton.Checked event, even though the former is inherited from the latter. Obviously, it was my misunderstanding. However, I think it would be more useful if we do have this kind of distinction. Anyway, I accepted your answer.

Comment: Hey, I just found the source of my misunderstanding: Page 164 of MacDonald's Pro WPF in C# 2010, he wrote: "Note  The Click event is actually defined in the ButtonBase class and inherited by the Button class. If you attach 
an event handler to ButtonBase.Click, that event handler will be used when any ButtonBase-derived control is 
clicked (including the Button, RadioButton, and CheckBox classes). If you attach an event handler to Button.Click, 
it’s only used for Button objects." Is it right?

Comment: For the reasons I described you can write `<CheckBox Button.Click="CheckBox_Click"/>` even though `CheckBox` is not derived from `Button` and the handler will still be called.  Therefore I would say the book is at least misleading.

Answer (score 1):

its because you are setting the event on the grid, so any children contained by the grid that have a `Checkbox.Checked` routed event will respond to the event.  In your case, it happens that the `ComboboxItem` uses the same routed event (and I am sure other controls probably reuse it as well)

the easiest way to handle this would be to add a test to your handler, something like this:

```
private void OnModified(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if ( sender is CheckBox )
    {
        CheckBox ckBox = sender as CheckBox;
        // do stuff with ckBox
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because both events get bubbled up the elements tree and both reach your handler (`CheckBox` inherits `ToggleButton`, hence `CheckBox.Checked` and `ToggleButton.Checked` are in fact the same events). You cannot prevent this. What you can do instead is to check whether the event was raised by a `CheckBox`. It can be done like this:

```
private void OnModified(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Filter the event by its source
    if (e.Source.GetType() != typeof(CheckBox))
        return;

    // Your handling code         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to prevent Checkbox.Checked event by checking if it is focused or not. Because when it fires from binding it is not Focused, but when you click on it than it is focused.

```
 if(cbo.IsFocused){ // code here }
```

Hope this helps.
Blerim.

Answer (score -2):

I'm the author of "Pro WPF in C# 2010" and I can confirm that the text from the Note box falls under the "what was I smoking?" category. There is no distinction between the Click event based on how you refer to it in your markup.

Matthew